# Maatwebsite excel set watermark in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I am using laravel 9 and using Maatwebsite. I want to make watermark in excel. Here I did

```
class myExport implements FromView, WithEvents ,WithDrawings
{

  public function view(): View
   {
     return view('report');
   }

   public function drawings()
    {
    $drawing = new Drawing();
    $drawing->setName('Background Text');
    $drawing->setDescription('This text ');
    $drawing->setPath(public_path('assets/img/draft.png'));
    $drawing->setCoordinates('A1'); 

    return [$drawing];
}
```

**But this image not appears in background. Also it will be ok if I set any text**

Thanks in advance.............

Answer (score 0):

Update this line of code.

```
 $drawing->setPath(public_path('assets/img/draft.png'));
```

To

```
 $drawing->setPath(asset('assets/img/draft.png'));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . But now no image is showing. In previous I abled to show image but couldn't made that as background image